# How to open a URL in python

Tags: python, bottle

```
import urllib

fun open():
    return urllib.urlopen('http://example.com')
```

But when example.com opens it does not render CSS or JavaScript. How can I open the webpage in a web browser?

```
@error(404)
def error404(error):
    return webbrowser.open('http://example.com')
```

I am using bottle. Giving me the error:

> ```
> TypeError("'bool' object is not iterable",)
> ```

Comment: It looks like we have a language disconnect. the `error` decorator seems to be expecting an iterable. `webbrowswer.open` will _open a url in the browser_ and return `True` or `False`, preserving [command-query-separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation). You don't actually want to open this page in the browswer, do you?

Comment: Do you want to download the javascript and css after you've already downloaded the html?

Comment: I concern is to open url in browser. If it is possible with downloding the js and css then it is OK.

Comment: just open the python interpreter and type `webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com')` and see if it does what you want.

Comment: yes. The result is same. But it always opens in mozilla.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

with the [webbrowser](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) module

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('http://example.com')  # Go to example.com
```

Comment: What the.. this always opens the internet explorer?!!!? D:
For the time being I used subprocess to call an explorer with the url as argument. This always uses the "default web browser" but also opens an explorer instance... hmmm

Comment: @ewerybody It is always going to open your default browser.

Comment: Well, this is 7 years ago I'm pretty sure I had Firefox as default browser even back then. Now this ^ also works for me 

Comment: [Quite some things](https://github.com/python/cpython/commits/main/Lib/webbrowser.py) happened on the module since then.

Answer (score 43):

```
import webbrowser  
webbrowser.open(url, new=0, autoraise=True)
```

Display url using the default browser. If new is 0, the url is opened in the same browser window if possible. If new is 1, a new browser window is opened if possible. If new is 2, a new browser page (“tab”) is opened if possible. If autoraise is True, the window is raised

```
webbrowser.open_new(url)
```

Open url in a new window of the default browser

```
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

Open url in a new page (“tab”) of the default browser

Answer (score 38):

On **Windows**

```
import os
os.system("start \"\" https://example.com")
```

On **macOS**

```
import os
os.system("open \"\" https://example.com")
```

On **Linux**

```
import os
os.system("xdg-open \"\" https://example.com")
```

**Cross-Platform**

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('https://example.com')
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to read the data too.

Check out : http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/urllib2/ to understand it.

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(..)
headers = response.info()
data = response.read()
```

Of course, what you want is to render it in browser and aaronasterling's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 8):

You could also try:

```
import os
os.system("start \"\" http://example.com")
```

This, other than @aaronasterling ´s answer has the advantage that it opens the default web browser.
Be sure not to forget the "http://".

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to do it.

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open("foobar.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the easy way to open a URL using this function

```
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who feel like not using `webbrowser`, here's my Windows-only solution with `os` instead:

```py
import os # `os.path` is still available through `os`!

sOFile = os.path.join(os.environ["TEMP"], "so.url") # Put StackOverflow's .URL file in %temp%
with open(sOFile, "w") as urlIO:
    urlIO.write("[InternetShortcut]\nURL=https://stackoverflow.com")
os.startfile(sOFile)
os.remove(sOFile)
```