# Opening a url in a *new window* (python)

Tags: python, url, web

I've been trying to use Python in order to open a certain webpage in a new window, and not in a new tab. From what I've heard :

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new('www.google.com')
```

should be used for a new window.
However, when I run the program, it opens the page in a new tab, and not in a new window.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/19002247/355230

Comment: Just don't do this, this pisses people off. I for one specifically set my browser to disable opening new windows. The option's there for a reason.