# How to run / open a specific document from a Python script?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to run / open a specific .txt document or a .html web page at the end of a process. I've looked everywhere for the solution to no avail. The closest I've come to what I need is:

```
import subprocess    
subprocess.call(["notepad.exe"])
```

but as you already may know, this only opens a blank notepad instance, which is not what I want.
Any ideas?

Comment: use `subprocess.popen(["notepad", "filename"])`

Comment: I did work for notepad, but how can I also open a webpage?

Comment: Never mind. I found the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302027/how-to-open-a-url-in-python

Comment: By the way,  `subprocess.popen(["notepad", "filename"])` doesn't work in Python 3, but `subprocess.Popen()`