# How to open url in Python

Tags: python-3.x, url

I'm trying to open verification link from email via python. But opening the link using the requests.get method does not work here, apparently the site has some JS code that should work. Is there some way to open a link other than through selenium?

Comment: I think that this question has been answered here [on Stack Overflow!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302027/how-to-open-a-url-in-python)