# Python: how to click on an opened outlook email (win32)

Tags: python, winapi, outlook

I need to click on an opened outlook email, a specific approve link that says "Approve request".

I opened the wanted email correctly, but I can't click on the specific link.
Here is the code:

```
import win32com.client

outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox=outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", Descending=True)

for i in range(100):
    message = messages.GetNext()
    print(""+message.Subject, str(message.ReceivedTime))
    if message.Subject == "Mail to approve request":
        message.Display(False)

    else:
        pass
```

Comment: What is the _approve_ button (do you have a screenshot) ? What is `text` and how should the button be shown?

Comment: It is a link that says "Approve Request"

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse the `MailItem.HTMLBody` property, extract the relevant link, launch the browser with that link.

Also, never loop through all items in a folder, use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` with a query like `"[Subject]='Mail to approve request'"`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to open a hyperlink programmatically in Python. The [How to open a URL in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302027/how-to-open-a-url-in-python) page explains possible scenarios. For example:

```
import os
os.system("start \"\" https://example.com")
```

Use the [HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) property which returns the a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. So, you may find the required URL programmatically by parsing the message body and execute it programmatically.

And, finally, to find items that correspond to your conditions use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

See [Filtering Items Using Query Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-query-keywords) for building a search criteria string properly.

Also you may find the `AdvancedSearch` method of the Application class helpful. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

Read more about this method in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.